# high order differential equation with matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

i know that  solution of system

$$\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} = A\vec{x}$$

where $A$ is matrix,is following

$$\vec{x}=\vec{\eta}e^{\lambda t}$$

I used resources from [this][1] web site

There is also method related for second order differential equation,which could be deduced to first order,but what about high order? For example third order? Let us consider such type of differential equation

$$y' + P(x)y = Q(x)y^n$$

which  could be solved by the substitution

$$\nu = y^{1-n}$$

But what if this is represented by matrix form? Could we substitute  just

$$B=A^{1-n}$$

where $B$ and $A$ are matrix? If so does not make it problem if  $A^{1-n}$  is zero? We know nilpotent definition for example, please help me to clarify this terms.

Comment: With higher order systems, it's not immediately clear to me how to cast them in the form $\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} = A\vec{x}$, where $A$ is a matrix because matrices are inherently linear operators whereas $y^n$ is a nonlinear function of $y$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams that is what i am interested in,is it possible  to apply matrix form and procedures?